# Why is my code in Java giving me so much trouble with if else statements in this specific line of code in Jgrasp?

Tags: java, jgrasp

Learning Java, now I do not know why but this code keeps giving me issues with `else if` statements.

```
public class Sherlock
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String answer = "Watson";
        String response = "";
        int tries = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (tries <=3); 
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the name of Sherlock's partner, and     dear friend. ");
            response = input.nextLine();
            tries++;

            if (response.equals ("Watson"))
            while (tries<= 3) 
            {
                System.out.println("Yes, that is right, Barrel Rider.");
                break;
            }
            else if (tries == 3)
            {
                System.out.println("Ooooh, sorry kid but it looks like you are     S.O.L.");
                break; 
            }
               else
               while (tries <= 3)
              {
           System.out.println("Sorry, try again!");
              }

        }
    }
}
```

The if else statement error has been more or less solved, but now I'm getting a different error:

Sherlock.java:24: error: break outside switch or loop
break;
^
1 error

Why does it keep insisting I put break outside the switch or loop?

Comment: I've formatted your code. Properly-formatted code is the first step in writing bug-free code. It makes it much easier to find things that shouldn't be there... like the erroneous semi-colons after your `while` loop statement and your first `if` statement.

Comment: Good eye Sherlock ;)

Comment: Thanks, Chris. You da bess.

Answer (score 1):

remove the semi-colons from the if statement

```
if (response.equals ("Watson"))
```

And the while loop

```
while (tries <=3)
```

These semi-colons are messing up the parsing of your control statements. The reason why the semi-colon after the if-statement messes things up is that the parser doesn't expect there to be a body due to the presence of the semi-colon, and therefore it doesn't expect there to be an else statement after an if-statement with no body.

In the future, I suggest that you make sure that you have checked your code for valid semantics and syntax. You will learn the basics about control statements from any good tutorial on YouTube.

Comment: I made the corrections, but now it is asking me to put the break outside the loop in the line above.

Comment: @Dark_Firaga Wy did you add a new loop under the if-statement? Remove that

Comment: Tebbs33 : Ooooooooooooh, I see.